# Setting all links in hyperref package to a custom color

Tags: hyperref

I want to set all links within my document to some `customcolor` (different from those available by default: `white`, `black`, `red`, `green`, `blue`, `cyan`, `magenta`, `yellow`). Is there a way to achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=%customcolor
]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use custom defined colors you have to load the `xcolor` package in the preamble, as it gives you a couple of predefined conversion tables, such as `RGB`, `CYMK`, etc.

Then invoke the following command like described:

`\definecolor{<custom name for color>}{<color model>}{<color values>}`

The values depend on the color model, e.g. for the HTML color model you need to express the color in HEX values (see example).

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{freakishgreen}{HTML}{0A982B}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=freakishgreen]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

colored links appear \href{here}{www.google.com}...

\end{document}
```

Edit:
As an alternative to `xcolor` there is the `color` package.